# Does Enterprise Library 1.0 support sql server 2005

Tags: enterprise-library

I used to connect to SQL Server2000. If it is possible to change to SQL Server2005? If yes, how to change the settings? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to MSSQL2k5 using basically the same connection strings, backwards compatibility is a major feature of the MS platform.

Be aware that you'll need to migrate tables, and possibly databases, into the new server's mounted databases.

The EntLib 1.0 code doesn't to my recollection take advantage of the features on MSSQL2k5.